# Need aptitude questions for php preparation

Tags: php

I need to prepare for PHP aptitude exam. I have searched on Google but I am not getting proper stuff for PHP aptitude.
I have some stuff of zend certification ( covered most of the concept ). Needed other stuff apart from zend certification.

Can any one provide me any links which has PHP aptitude questions ?
w

Comment: i know what php is, i know what aptitude is—but what i don't know is what php aptitude is. can you explain?

Comment: @knittl I *think* he is referring to "being apt in PHP" in general, but I may be wrong. @OP please provide some info about your exam. How would you answer if I asked you "I'm going to take a math exam tomorrow. Can you provide me with some example questions"? Wouldn't your first question be what kind of exam: Kindergarten? Elementary school? High school? Uni? The same applies here.

Comment: I am sorry, there is no such meaning of php aptitude, it's set of question with answers for php, which is basically i'll use for preparing php exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is admittedly a very basic level quiz, but you can check here:  [w3schools PHP quiz](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_quiz.asp)

Other than that; we'll need more info as to the level of your exam.

Answer (score 3):

You can try Brainbench.com. They have tests for just about anything, including PHP. The tests are pretty thorough. They do cost money, but the PHP 5.3 Beta test is currently free.